# Legacy VMware Player on modern Linux

Tags: vmware, vmware-player, manjaro

I have a requirement for Unity mode on a Linux host with a Windows guest. Virtualbox does not implement Seamless mode well, and the likes of Winapps or Cassowary have other issues that make multiple monitor setups a problem.

On Majaro 23, I have installed VMware Player 7 from the player bundle, and have added the service workers as demonstrated [here](https://computingforgeeks.com/install-vmware-workstation-on-arch-linux-manjaro/), but the player binary does not start. Starting it via terminal (from /usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware) results in no output at all. Attempting to use vmware-modconfig results in an unspecified segmentation fault.

Is there a way to install Player 7 in this OS? If not this OS, perhaps a debian distro?

Comment: Player 7 is long gone.  Player 17 is current. No support for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Support isn't an issue, this vm will be entirely offline. I'm just posting in the hope that someone more knowledgeable than I might have attempted this with a little more success.

Comment: I doubt Player 7 will work properly (and possibly not even at all).  (I have used VMware Workstation and Player since Version 1).

Comment: Why don't you download and use the latest VMware Player version?

Comment: @harrymc Unity mode on a linux host is a requirement. VMware removed this in WS 11 and WMP 7.

Comment: @John I did have some success getting it running at one point, but I was unable to build modules for it

Comment: Unity mode (I have used it) was not as effective as VMware thought it might be and they gave it up.

Comment: Perhaps try `VMWARE_USE_SHIPPED_GTK=yes vmplayer`, although I'm not optimistic that you would be able to power-on VMs or use Unity.